# Rails: Show and hide a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app and I'm looping through some db values:

```
<ul>
  <% @categories.each do |category| %>
    <li onclick="showHide(event)"> <%= category.name %>
      <% unless category.children.empty? %>
        <ul class="categories" style="display:none;">
          <% category.children.each do |subcategory| %>
            <li><%=  link_to "#{subcategory.name}", search_path(:search => subcategory.id) %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
     <% end %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

And with the following javascript I'm able to show and hide the div when I click on it:

```
function showHide(e) {
  var categoryList = e.currentTarget.querySelector(".categories");
  categoryList.style.display = categoryList.style.display === "none" ? "block" : "none"
}
```

This does work, but I need to implement two more things to this.
1. When I click on one category and another one is open, I want to close the other one. 
2. Even after I refresh the page, I want to figure out a way to remember the last target(the last div that was open).

Any ideas on how to implement both of the above?

**Update 1**

Ok I followed @Panomosh advise I got the first one to work. And on the second one when the cookie doesn't exist I create it and then it gives me this error in the browser console:

`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'categoryList.currentTarget.querySelector')`

Any ideas why?

```
function getCookie(c_name) {
    var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
        x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
        x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
        if (x == c_name) {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}

function showHide(e) {
    var divsToHide = document.getElementsByClassName("categories"); 
    for(var i = 0; i < divsToHide.length; i++){
        divsToHide[i].style.display = "none"; // depending on what you're doing
    }

    var myCookie = getCookie(".Cl");

    if (myCookie == null) {
        var categoryList = e.currentTarget.querySelector(".categories");
        setCookie(".Cl", categoryList)
        categoryList.style.display = categoryList.style.display === "none" ? "block" : "none"

}
    else {
        var categoryList = getCookie(".Cl");
        categoryList.currentTarget.querySelector(".categories");
        categoryList.style.display = categoryList.style.display === "none" ? "block" : "none"
    }
}

function setCookie(c_name, value) {
    var now = new Date();
    var time = now.getTime();
    time += 300 * 1000;
    now.setTime(time);
    var c_value = escape(value) + ((time == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + now.toUTCString());
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
```

Comment: 1. When a Div is clicked, close all of the divs before you open the target. 2. create a new var in the global scope to store the previously opened target in.

Comment: I agree with @Panomosh on how to solve problem 1. However, for your second problem, if you want to preserve a user's state through a refresh, creating a browser cookie is probably the easiest and most straightforward way to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the replies @Panomosh! I got the first part to work, check out my question I added an update on how I'm doing this. But the second one I'm having difficulty. Kind of a newbie with javascript, so help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the replies @Rob Nice! I got the first part to work, check out my question I added an update on how I'm doing this. But the second one I'm having difficulty. Kind of a newbie with javascript, so help would be very much appreciated.